# Adding days to the select query result dates in oracle

Tags: date, oracle12c

select from_date_su_rela,to_date_su_rela from RELATION_T;

[image: to_date_su_rela+56]

But the expectation is reducing -56 days from the first row from_date_su_rela and adding the +56 days to last(3rd) row to_date_su_rela. as below

[image]

I have written query as ,

select from_date_su_rela-56,to_date_su_rela+56 from RELATION_T; But its adding and reducing days from all the rows as below,

[image]

How to make it working as above 2nd image.

Comment: How do you know that you want to subtract from the first row and add to the third row?  Will there always be exactly three rows?  If there are more rows or fewer rows, which row will you add to?  The third?  The last?  Something else?  How are you defining "first" and "third"?  Are you ordering by the `from_date`?  The `to_date`?  Or some other column?

Comment: Yes ordering by from_date. The rows are always first and last. Everytime not three row it may be one or many.

Comment: OK.  So you want to subtract from the first row and add to the last row.  Not necessarily the third row.  If there is only one row, I assume you want to both add and subtract on that row?  Is it possible for there to be two rows with the same `from_date`?  If so, how are ties handled?

Comment: from_date is a primary key. So no two rows have the same from_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `row_number` analytic function sorting the data both ascending and descending to find the first and last row and then perform the addition and subtraction in a `case` statement

```
select case when rn_asc = 1
            then from_date_su_rela - 56
            else from_date_su_rela
         end from_date_su_rela,
       case when rn_desc = 1
            then to_date_su_rela + 56
            else to_date_su_rela
         end to_date_su_rela
  from (
      select from_date_su_rela,
             to_date_su_rela,
             row_number() over (order by from_date_su_rela desc) rn_desc,
             row_number() over (order by from_date_su_rela asc) rn_asc
        from relation_t
  )
```

Comment: If i want to display other columns of the same table relation_t like abc,xyz etc.. where i can add these columns.

Comment: @Gangs165700 - You'd add them to both the inline view and the outer select.